# Write Java 3d objects to custom file type

Tags: java, serialization, encoding, binary, java-3d

So, my problem has basically two sub-problems.
I want to create my custom file type, probably with UTF-8 encoding. I think I can do that only by saving a file with prefered extension with some method I don't know yet to set encoding to UTF-8, or anything that would fit.
My extension would be ".molb".

Now, the problem is that I need to write 3d Objects, such as Spheres and Cylinders to that file, and when I open the file, to be recognized and added to my Universe in some way.
Some articles were suggesting Serializing objects and using FileBuffers, but none actually helped me understand how can I apply this to my own problem.

To clarify, I will give the following example:
[This image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/840/whatineed.jpg/)
shows some objects (a cylinder and a sphere) that should be saved in a form or another, in a file so when that file is opened, the objects appear with the saved atributes (position, color, orientation etc).Also my file would contain an Array storing the xyz positions of the spheres

Comment: Can you provide us with more information? like for instance the dimensions of your x,y,z axis or matrices? and what have you done so far? giving SO the brief but not any background doesn't really help anybody.

Comment: What I will need to write will be a bunch of arrays that store the positions of some Spheres, the actual spheres and cylinders. The program should be able to build molecules, so the spheres will be the atoms and the cylinders the bounds. All the visible data (cylinders and spheres) are in a TransformGroup, so for now it would be enough to be able to write the transformgroup and the arrays to the file, that supposing that I could also fix the adresses of the elements to be constant, or to find another way acces elements, even if the file contains the transformgroup itself.

Comment: Just write the array as text to a file in a specific order.
Then you can read it back in that order and rerender it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your classes implement `Serializable` you can write them to file very simply.

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile.molb"));
os.writeObject(sphare);
os.close();
```

This file is binary. You do not have to care about encoding.

If however you want to serialize your object using XML, JSON or other text format you will probably want to open wrap stream with writer using other constructor that accepts encoding: `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("my.txt"), "UTF-8)"`.
You will also have to add some annotations (e.g. JAXB or Jakson) to enable object-to-xml (or json) serialization.